# The sum of three consecutive integers is 48. Find the integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well, guys, I tired and it answer is...
What's your answer?!

Let the middle of three consecutive integers be $= X$.  Therefore, the other two integers will be $X + 1$ and $x - 1$.  By the problem,
\begin{align*}
(X - 1) + X + X + 1 & = 48\\
X - 1  + X + X + 1 & = 48\\
3X & = 48\\
X & = 48 \div 3 = 16\\
X - 1 & = 16 - 1 = 15\\
X + 1 & = 16 + 1 = 17
\end{align*}

Therefore, the three consecutive integers $= 15, 16, 17$.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but what is your question?

Comment: Your first equation is $$x-1+x+6+1=48$$?

Comment: The sum of three consecutive integers is 48. Find the integers.

Comment: Please do not use $x$ and $X$ to mean the same thing.  Doing so is confusing.  You stated the three numbers were $x - 1$,  $x$, and $x + 1$.   Therefore, their sum should be $x - 1 + x + x + 1$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You have two typos.  The $6$ in the first equation should be $X$ and in the second paragraph you say $x$ when you mean $X$.  They are not the same.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear how you transform your equation: the three numbers are $x-1$, $x$ and $x+1$, so the equation is
$$
(x-1)+x+(x+1)=48
$$
that obviously becomes
$$
3x=48
$$
Since this gives $x=16$, the three numbers are $15$, $16$ and $17$.

Answer (score 0):

The middle term is A.M. of the first and last. Since thrice the middle term is 48, 
it is 16. Add 1 for next term and subrtract 1 for the previous one.